# Using cbind to take values from a dataframe to a matrix to do partition data into test/train for knn

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, partitioning

I'm trying to run a knn for prediction, and im having trouble partitioning the data in a way that R will accept it for using the function. It seems to have a problem at the cbind step. There might be additional problems after but I haven't gotten past the ## step yet. Here is my code

```
library(class)
set.seed(1)
a<-runif(10)
b<-runif(10)
c<-rnorm(10)
sample_outcome<-sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10)
sample.df<-data.frame(a,b,c,sample_outcome)
stack_smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(sample.df))
sample_train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(sample.df)), size = stack_smp_size)
sample_train <- sample.df[sample_train_ind, ]
sample_test <- sample.df[-sample_train_ind, ]
###Problem here
sample_train_x <-cbind(a,b,c)[sample_train,]
sample_test_x <-cbind(a,b,c)[!sample_train,]
sample_train_outcome<-sample_outcome[sample_train]
sample_knn=knn(sample_train_x,sample_test_x,sample_train_outcome,k=1)
```

Comment: You should look at the details of the `cbind.data.frame` function, `cbind` being generic. My memory is that any dataframe in the arguments will effectively prevent the result from being a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

`sample_train` is a dataframe.

```
class(sample_train)
#[1] "data.frame"
```

`cbind(a, b, c)` gives a matrix. I am not sure what do you expect to happen when you subset a matrix with the dataframe (`sample_train_x <-cbind(a,b,c)[sample_train_ind,]`).

I think what you might be looking for is :

```
library(class)

sample_train_x <- cbind(a,b,c)[sample_train_ind,]
sample_test_x <- cbind(a,b,c)[-sample_train_ind,]
sample_train_outcome <- sample_outcome[sample_train_ind]
sample_knn = knn(sample_train_x,sample_test_x,sample_train_outcome,k=1)
```

Comment: Thank you that helped, I now get an error at the line  "sample_train_outcome<-sample_outcome[sample_train]", the error is    "Error in sample_outcome[sample_train] : invalid subscript type 'list",

Comment: @PortMadeleineCrumpet Why are you using `sample_train` to subset `sample_outcome` ? In my answer I am using `sample_train_outcome <- sample_outcome[sample_train_ind]` i.e `sample_train_ind` and not `sample_train`